# How to make angular consider STRING '+' as a operator

Tags: angularjs

I am taking the symbols (+,-,*,/) from a dropdown. When i try to use the symbol for adding, it just displays as string.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$eval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Like this

```
console.log($scope.$eval("1+1"));
```

In view

```
{{$eval("1+1")}}
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/eubkvjv0/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside `{{}}` is angular bindings. If the expression is given as `{{"1+1"}}` angular treats it as a string and displays the string as it is.

`$eval` is a method on `$scope` that executes the expression on the current scope. so we can use `{{$eval("1+1")}}` which outputs 2 as a result.